# How to use AREL when using multiple databases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, arel, multiple-databases

When invoking Table(*column_symbol*) arel assumes that we are using the main database.

How can I use arel tables in a second database without having to ARModels for each of the queried tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table = Arel::Table.new("db_name.table_name")`

Answer (score 1):

works fine for me.

specify your "second database" params in config/database.yml

and in your model, specify `establish_connection :db_params`

Comment: The question was how to use Arel without using AR models.